# How to separate or filter nginx error log levels

Tags: nginx, logging, nginx-config, error-log, log-level

as I understood in nginx I could specify an error  log  as warn , error , info , debug , ...

my problem is that I wanna have warn logs and error logs on separate files but as you know if I a specify a file for warn logs then It would include error logs too

so I will have a file containing only error log and another file containing both error log and warn log

but I wanna have a file just for errors and another just for warns

how can I separate them entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can achieve what you want by having `error_log` logging to [syslog](http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html).

Then create a "rule" in rsyslog configuration to forward different severities to different files.